# Javascript Сортировка массива/Вывод списка

Tags: javascript, массивы, списки

```
$.each(data.data, function(idx, data){
     $("#res2").append('<tr><td>' + data.CityRef + '</td><td>' + data.CityDescription + '</td></tr>');
});
```

в массиве у меня список городов и областей вот пример вывода:

```
Киев   | Киевская обл.
Ирперь | Киевская обл.
Москва | Московская обл.
```

Получается с каждым выводом пишется область и она часто повторяется.
Вопрос как сделать что ли группировку городов по их областям? (чтобы одна область выводилась один раз) вот так:

```
-Киевская обл.
--Киев
--Ирпень
-Московская обл.
--Москва
...
```

Comment: Можешь через lodash группировать массив

Comment: @Alex78191, каким методом?

Comment: методом groupBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data= [
 {city: 'Киев', obl: 'Киевская обл.'},
 {city: 'Ирперь', obl: 'Киевская обл.'},
 {city: 'Москва', obl: 'Московская обл.'}
];

// Переберем массив в объект, где города разложены по областям.
const sorted = data.reduce((result, el) => {
    if(result[el.obl]) result[el.obl].push(el.city);
    else result[el.obl] = [el.city];
    return result;
},{});

// Выведем.
for(let obl in sorted){
    document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML += '<tr><td>-</td><td>' + obl + '</td></tr>';
    for(let city in sorted[obl])
        document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML += '<tr><td>--</td><td>' + sorted[obl][city] + '</td></tr>';
}
```

```html
<table id = 'res2'></table>
```

Comment: Отличное решение, подошло на ура. Но подскажите а можно теперь это вывести ul-списком где города будут вложенным ul в парент ul области?

Comment: @programmer403 Можно, в чем проблема? У вас на руках объект, где ключ - это область, а значение - массив городов в этой области. Делайте с ним что хотите)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю решение "в лоб", набросал такую функцию:

```
function groupBy(array, fieldName) {
    var result = [];
    var currentArray = array;
    while(currentArray.length > 0) {
        var element = currentArray[0];
        var groupValue = element[fieldName];
        var values = currentArray.filter(function (value) {
                return value[fieldName] == groupValue;
            });
        currentArray = currentArray.filter(function (value) {
            return value[fieldName] != groupValue;
        });

        values = values.map(function (value) {
            delete value[fieldName];
            return value;
        });

        result.push({
            group : groupValue,
            values : values
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Основная идея формировать не список, а результирующий массив, что иногда может быть полезно.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/1zsjdtd4/)